# How to display text different place than the source in LaTeX?

Tags: input

As an example: I would like to put the text of a math problem and the solution of the problem in the same input file next to each other, but in the pdf book I want to separate them into different sections. How to do it?

Comment: `\clearpage`? `\section`? your question is very less specific

Comment: Don't close yet; give the OP some time to clarify.

Comment: The `answers` package can do this for you. It will write the solutions to another file, which you can `\input` later in your document.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on my answer at [Equation summary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140702/equation-summary/140704#140704) (also related: [Lemma numbering by first instance of referencing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113337/lemma-numbering-by-first-instance-of-referencing/113441#113441)), except that I had to make it so that the equation numbers were not defined when the equation was defined, but only later when it was presented. (in that sense, it was easier than the referenced answers).

The macro `\retainmatter{}` allows an answer to be defined without presenting it, while `\recallmatter` will recall a previously retained answer.

The recalled answers still must appear in the order they were defined, though that could be changed with a little work.

As shown in the MWE, there is nothing that prevents text + equations from being part of the retained/recalled matter.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newcounter{retained}\setcounter{retained}{0}
\newcounter{shown}\setcounter{shown}{0}
\newcounter{saveequation}
\newcommand\retainmatter[1]{%
  \addtocounter{retained}{1}%
  \long\expandafter\gdef\csname defeq\roman{retained}\endcsname{#1}%
}
\newcommand\recallmatter{%
  \addtocounter{shown}{1}%
  \csname defeq\roman{shown}\endcsname%
}
\begin{document}

\section{Problems}

\begin{enumerate}

\item In this problem we are trying to express equation~\ref{eq:p1}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:p1}
y = x^n
\end{equation}
for the case when $n=1$.

The answer can be found in equation~\ref{eq:a1}.
\retainmatter{%
\fbox{\parbox{3in}{\textbf{Answer 1:}\\
Here, we perform a simple substitution and obtain the result
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:a1}
y = x
\end{equation}
}}}%

\item For this problem, we are trying to express equation~\ref{eq:p2}
for the case when $k=3$
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:p2}
y = x^k
\end{equation}

The answer can be found at equation~\ref{eq:a2}.
\retainmatter{%
\fbox{\parbox{3in}{\textbf{Answer 2:}\\
Here, we again perform a simple substitution and obtain the result
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:a2}
y = x^3
\end{equation}
}}}%
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Answers}

The answers to the problems are:\medskip

\recallmatter\medskip

\recallmatter

\section{Next Section}

Did equation numbers pick up in the right place?

\begin{equation}
 y = x^5
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]