# Displaying text from current page on the next page

Tags: cross-referencing

I am trying to place text in the footer of the next page. That is i have a question environment which defines the question and its solution but i want the solution to be displayed at the end of the next page. Either in the footer or just after the paragraphs of that text. Any help.

```
\documentclass{myclass}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
  \question{What is the earth age}
  \answer{14 billion} % the answer should be displayed at the 
   %end of the next page
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please give us an Minimal Working Example. Some code to play around with. We don't want to write everything from scratch and we need to know your documentclass. Do you need a footnote-number next to your question (like from `\footnote{}`) or does the reader know, that there will be a solution on the next pages footer?

Comment: I edited the post.. In fact that can be couple answers.

Comment: This might be related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179489/how-to-display-text-different-place-than-the-source-in-latex

Comment: Perhaps your looking for something like the `exam` package, with delayed `solution` display?

Comment: I have the exam package. I am actually developing a package for a lecture who want to write a book with questions and answers.

Comment: @Enem: Perhaps we should collaborate ;-) I am working for months on such a package and still improving it

Comment: We need more information in order to address this problem, perhaps showing some examples of what the output should look like. I'm voting to close as unclear until more information is provided.